# WCF REST: remove prefix "ArrayOf" for wcf method response

Tags: wcf, list, serialization, rest, response

Here is one of the methods from my wcf rest service:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "getInvoices", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
List<InvoiceRet> GetInvoices(GetInvoices getInvoices);
```

And it returns response in the next format:

```
<ArrayOfInvoiceRet>
  <InvoiceRet></InvoiceRet>
  <InvoiceRet></InvoiceRet>
  ...
  <InvoiceRet></InvoiceRet>
</ArrayOfInvoiceRet>
```

How to modify method to return the next response

```
<ListInvoice>
  <InvoiceRet></InvoiceRet>
  <InvoiceRet></InvoiceRet>
  ...
  <InvoiceRet></InvoiceRet>
</ListInvoice>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to implement custom collection derived from `List<InvoiceRet>` and mark it with `CollectionDataContractAttribute`:

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class ListInvoice : List<InvoiceRet>
{ }
```

Use this collection as return type from your operation. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx) is full description of using collections in data contracts.

Comment: This technique is not working for me in WCF .net 4.5 and has the same behaviour as if it is List<InvoiceRet>