# Annotation for WCF DataContractSerializer to replace ArrayOf with a custom name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, annotations, iqueryable, datacontractserializer, asp.net-mvc-4

I have succesfully implemented a RESTful Web Service using the .NET 4.0 framework with MVC 4 and the `ApiController` class.
I have a method, let's say `GetMovies` ("/api/movies") that returns an `IQueryable<Movie>`. Serialization is done using `DataContractSerializer`, of course. The problem is in the name of the returned list, because it is `ArrayOfMovie`:

```
<ArrayOfMovie>
    <Movie></Movie>
    <Movie></Movie>
    ...
    <Movie></Movie>
</ArrayOfMovie>
```

I cannot create a custom class, let's say `Movies`, and add a `[CollectionDataContract(Name = "movies")]` annotation (as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4593167/801065) because I cannot extend `IQueryable` without implementing all of its methods. And I most definitely need an IQueryable for OData/jQuery processing.
How can I solve this? Is there an annotation that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found.
You need to put a group class in the main class you want to serialize.

```
[DataContract(Name = "movies")]
public class group
{
    [DataMember(Name="movies")]
    public IQueryable<Movie> Movies;
}
```